Creating simple graphical model to convert to current epoch
I'm just working on a few projects in which files always need to be converted from GDA2020 to ITRF2014.
I have a pretty good process with the 'Convert Format tool' in which I enter into the advanced parameters section "-t_srs EPSG:9000 -t_coord_epoch 2024.78".
But to streamline this, I want to auto calculate the current epoch (2024.78) and create a graphical model of it this shift. I currently have two steps in my graphical model which I will post below. The calculation of the current epoch is easy, but just referencing this calculation in the GDAl Convert format part is the bit I am stuck on.


